# Would like to relate commit in official cpython library to a python release

Tags: python, version-control, cpython

I'm currently using a package provided to me in a whl file. I was able to install this package using `pip`. However, when I looked through the source code, it appears that the package expects the `_special` attribute to exist in the `_GenericAlias` class of the `typing` module. In the latest version of python's `typing` module, it looks like this attribute is not present. However, it looks like it did exist at a certain point in time as shown in [this link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6292be7adf247589bbf03524f8883cb4cb61f3e9/Lib/typing.py#L659).

I would like to figure out which version of python I need to install for this attribute to exist in the `typing` module. I can see from the link above that this was the case in commit  `6292be7adf` but I haven't a clue how to relate this commit to a specific python version that I can `pip` or `conda` install in my environment.

How can I come up with the exact version that contains the above code?

Comment: Pinning your code (or using a package that is so pinned) to a non-release commit in order to make use of a non-public attribute of a non-public class seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: I really don't have much of a choice here. The package is pretty much closed source and was provided as a whl file, so that's the only way I can make use of it for the time being.

What makes you think this is a non-release commit? I'm pretty sure the package was developed with a specific python release in mind. The only disadvantage here is that I'm unaware of which release it was....

Answer (score 1):

Ok I cloned the whole cpython repo and did a search:

```
$ git log -S 'self._special = special'
commit c1c7d8ead9eb214a6149a43e31a3213c52448877
Author: Serhiy Storchaka <storchaka@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu May 7 04:09:33 2020 +0300

    bpo-40397: Refactor typing._GenericAlias (GH-19719)

    Make the design more object-oriented.
    Split _GenericAlias on two almost independent classes: for special
    generic aliases like List and for parametrized generic aliases like List[int].
    Add specialized subclasses for Callable, Callable[...], Tuple and Union[...].

commit d911e40e788fb679723d78b6ea11cabf46caed5a
Author: Ivan Levkivskyi <levkivskyi@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Jan 20 11:23:59 2018 +0000

    bpo-32226: PEP 560: improve typing module (#4906)

    This PR re-designs the internal typing API using the new PEP 560 features.
    However, there are only few minor changes in the public API.
```

So this attribute was introduced in `d911e40e788fb679723d78b6ea11cabf46caed5a` which is in `3.7.0b1` and removed in `c1c7d8ead9eb214a6149a43e31a3213c52448877` which is in `3.9.0b1`. Anything in `3.7` or `3.8` should have it.

Comment: I need a version *with* this commit

Comment: tags with this commit are: v3.11.0a4  v3.11.0a3 v3.11.0a2 v3.11.0a1 v3.10.2 v3.10.1 v3.10.0 v3.10.0rc2 v3.10.0rc1 v3.10.0b4 v3.10.0b3 v3.10.0b2 v3.10.0b1 v3.10.0a7 v3.10.0a6 v3.10.0a5 v3.10.0a4 v3.10.0a3 v3.10.0a2 v3.10.0a1 v3.9.10 v3.9.9 v3.9.8 v3.9.7 v3.9.6 v3.9.5 v3.9.4 v3.9.3 v3.9.2 v3.9.2rc1 v3.9.1 v3.9.1rc1 v3.9.0 v3.9.0rc2 v3.9.0rc1 v3.9.0b5 v3.9.0b4 v3.9.0b3 v3.9.0b2 v3.9.0b1 v3.9.0a6 which you can see by clicking the `...` in the tag range.

Comment: I'm trying it now. Hopefully I can accept your answer in a few moments

Comment: Sorry, I just tried `conda install python=3.9.0`, but `typing.py` is still the same!

Comment: The attribute you want was removed in c1c7d8ead9. The only "release" that might actually include that attribute is v3.9.0a6, which is the only tag I can see between 6292be7adf and c1c7d8ead9. If it were me, I would not rely on an alpha version to work properly.

Comment: Ok completely changed my answer as I was chasing your commit and not looking where that line appears and disappears.

Comment: Oops, I didn't check if 6292be7adf was the *earliest* commit with the attribute. Just FYI, you can use `git tag -l --contains d911e40e7 --no-contains c1c7d8ead9` to see the tags between the two commits.